# is there a way to do a BigQuery query in Google Sheets with a named range?

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I'm using the new **Google Sheets - Bigquery** data connector to download Bigquery data into a Google Sheet.

I'd like to try to make it more interactive for people who don't know anything about SQL.

Is there currently any way to use a cell reference and/or named range in my BigQuery query?

e.g. I have a cell on the Google Sheet called "Customer".
Is there a way to use that in my BigQuery query so I'm doing something like

```
Select * where customer_name = Customer
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@namedRangeCustomer would be the proper syntax

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

When connecting your data, opt for the custom query option presented at the bottom. This will bring up a dialog window like the attached, you can set up parameters here that can reference cell values.

```
select *
from `dataset.table`
where column = @parameter_name
```

[Custom query prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRxBE.png)

Answer (score -1):

```
=QUERY(A:B, "select * where A = 'Customer'")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I read the question in totally different way. interesting to see if OP actually meant what is answered above :o)

Comment: Thanks player0. I'm talking about the BigQuery query from within the BigQuery data connector. I just added an image to my original question to try to make it more clear.